# If $P \in \operatorname{Ass}M$, then $R/P \subset M$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. $M$ an $R$-module. Then $P \in \operatorname{Ass}M$ if and only if there is a submodule $N\subset M$ such that $R/P \cong N$.

$$\operatorname{Ass}M:=\{P\text{ prime $R$-ideal}\mid P\text{ is the annihilator of an element of }M\}$$

I think all I need is a hint. Could somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: It is usually good for exercises like this to provide the definition you are using.  "$P$ is prime, and $M$ has a submodule isomorphic to $R/P$" is equivalent to the condition that $P$ is an associated prime, and can be used as the definition itself.

Comment: Also, something is strange in the question—I don't think you should have the line about $R/P\subset M$ at all, because there is no natural way to identify elements of $R/P$ with elements of $M$.  Saying that there is some $N\subset M$ isomorphic to $R/P$ is a much more precise and correct version of the same statement.

Comment: Thanks. I supplied the definition, but I see you have already supplied an answer below.

Comment: There's a problem with this definition: It is not enough that $P$ annihilates an element of $M$.  It be _be the annihilator_ of an element of $m$.  In other words, nothing outside of $P$ can annihilate $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that, for you, an associated prime $P$ of $R$ is a prime ideal that is the annihilator of some nonzero $m\in M$, and that you want to show that this implies that there is some submodule of $M$ isomorphic to $R/P$.

Here is my hint: As part of the condition, we are given a nonzero $m\in M$.  Using this, construct a homomorphism of modules $R\to M$, and compute its kernel.

Comment: I think this works: Given $P=ann(m)$, let $\phi:R \rightarrow M$ be given by $r \mapsto rm$. Then $ker(\phi)=P$. Then by the first isomorphism theorem, we have $R/P \cong Im\phi$.

Comment: @user151852 This is exactly right, modulo my complaint about the definition.

Answer (score 0):

let $p=Ann\ x$ for some $x\in M$. then 
$$R/P\cong R/Ann\ x\cong Rx\subset M$$